# How to handle empty values in sql table

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please help me to get result as expected in output using sql server query?

[image]

Comment: Hi! First of all - welcome on StackOverflow. Be sure to check out here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour
Also - please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking questions. Good day to you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE`

```
SELECT
  Store,
  CASE WHEN ISNULL(Item,'') = '' THEN 'NA or 999' ELSE Item END AS Item, 
  CASE WHEN ISNULL(Input,'') = '' THEN 'NA or 999' ELSE Input END as Input
FROM 
  Table
```